# How to populate dynamic content on listview?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, ios6

I want to populate list of items, which are coming in "data jsonp" format in a listview. I am using jquery mobile and phonegap. I have tried all possibles but instead of coming in listview, data is coming in simple  format. I am using "jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" and "jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js".
please help.

It would be great if someone provide some working examples.

thanks ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the data to be presented in enhanced jQuery mobile format you need to

1. Add the data to the DOM in list format, with a `data-role="listview"` attribute

   ```
   <ul id="listContainer" data-role="listview">
       <li>Item 1</li>
       <li>Item 2</li>
       <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
   ```

   (you can have the `</ul>` already present in the DOM, and add the items from the JSON list within it)
2. Enhance the content with jQuery mobile, with `$("#listContainer").listview("refresh");`

You can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rgJf2/)

Comment: Yes I am defining like this only. I am able to  show data but listview  is not coming. Below i posted my code. see

Comment: did you call $("#output").listview(); after adding the content ?

Comment: yes. But no change. No listview is coming, just data in plain format.

Comment: is there any jquery-mobile css problem. Because  I can't see any error in my code.

Comment: You need to use .listview("refresh"); I have added a link to a jsFiddle with your example working

Comment: Thanks Romain. it's working and i really appreciate it. But it didn't solve my problem.
This listview is just a static listview, it's not a clickable jquery-mobile listview. How can I make it clickable and jqury-mobile theme supported?

Comment: To make it clickable you just need to add a link to it. I have updated the link to the fiddle in my answer to show you

Comment: Thanks Romain million times. It works :) I was stuck for 2 weeks in this and finally solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

First you should add a list view:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="SomeListView" class="tab">
</ul>
```

Then , fill listview by fetched service data:

```
$.getJSON(globalServiceUrl + "mobile/services/getSomeData.json", function (json) {
    var html = '';

    $.each(json, function (k, v) {
        var item= json[k];
        html += '<li>'+item.Title+'</li>';
    });

    $("#SomeListView").html(html);
    $("#SomeListView").listview('refresh');
 }); // $.getJSON
```

Comment: Hi Peiman.
the "html+" procedure is not working. I am unable to display data from json file only. i have attache my json format please see and I replaced item.Title with item.name according to my json. But it's not working.

Comment: ([{"id":"1","name":"Big Ben","latitude":"51.500600000000","longitude":"-0.124610000000"},{"id":"4","name":"Hadrian's Wall","latitude":"55.024453000000","longitude":"2.142310000000"},{"id":"2","name":"Stonehenge","latitude":"51.178850000000","longitude":"-1.826446000000"},{"id":"3","name":"White Cliffs of Dover","latitude":"51.132020000000","longitude":"1.334070000000"}]);

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
    //Phonegap ready
    onDeviceReady();
});

var output = $('#output');

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://samcroft.co.uk/demos/updated-load-data-into-phonegap/landmarks.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
       $.each(data, function(i, item) {
              $('ul').append('<li><h4>' + item.name + '</h4><p>' + item.latitude + '<br>' + item.longitude + '</p></li>');
              });
    },
    error: function(){
       output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});
```

});

```
<body>
    <div>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="false" id="output" >

        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my code.